# IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'arc' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The radius provided (-0.5) is negative

Tags: charts, ionic-framework, chart.js

I am using charts from chart.js in my ionic app, i faced the following problem.
The Chart is working pretty good once the view appears, even when navigating through tabs without writing in input. But When:

I am in Tab1.

I try to change Tab to Tab2 that contains Input text.

then when the keyboard is appearing, i write or not.

I dismiss the keyboard (That's what cause the problem)

I go back to the Tab1

The Chart is disappearing and not reappearing until closing the application.
if i don't dismiss the keyboard the chart will appear
I am not using any extra code for handling the chart
 if anyone having any crack or solution please help.